# Why is one cookie missed?

Tags: c#, cookies, cookiecontainer, missing-cookies

I'm scrapping a page which is the result of a redirect: I visit page1 first, then it redirects to page2 via `http-equiv="refresh"`. I'm scrapping page2. Content on page2 is based on some cookies page1 sets. I see page1 returns 2 cookies, but when I request page 2 (sending the same `CookieContainer`, one cookie is missing. What's wrong in my code?

Thank you:

**First** : 
I create a `CookieContainer` and an `HttpWebRequest` and request for page1.

`HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(eQuery);

req.AllowAutoRedirect = true; // but it doesn't autoredirects the meta-refresh
 
req.CookieContainer = cookiesContainer;`

This is the result I get this from visiting page1

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK 

Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2011 19:14:06 GMT
 
Server: (...)

Set-Cookie: NAME1=VALUE1; path=/

Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0

Pragma: no-cache

Set-Cookie: NAME2=VALUE2; expires=Wed, 13-Apr-2011 19:14:06 GMT

Content-Length: 174

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Type: text/html

(...)`

Everything is fine so far, I get two cookies are there and I get two cookie objects within the container.

Then I parse the "content" value of the `meta http-equiv` for the next url. And request it using a similar code and using the same container. But only one cookie is sent. Here is the HTTP sent:

`GET DETECTED_URL_IN_HTTP_EQUIV_REFRESH HTTP/1.1 

User-Agent: (...) 

Host: example.com 

Cookie: NAME1=VALUE1`

As you see cookie NAME2 is missing. Why is that happening? is something related differences in the two cookies (one has path and other has expiration date)?
Any idea how can I pass the two cookies?

PS: I don't have access to page1, so I can't set path, or expiration for cookies. I'm scrapping those pages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a path on your cookie it will default to the path it was requested on. So if you received a cookie on this request with no path declaration:

```
http://contoso.com/subfolder/test.aspx
```

The browser would only send back that cookie for more requests in the `/subfolder/` directory. To have the browser send it back for all paths you need to include `path=/` when setting the cookie.

Comment: Thank you, however I don't have access to include the `path=/` in the cookie since I'm scrapping a server I don't have access to. I will see what can I do. Thank you anyway.